# Sub-domain's Route Name

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4, wildcard-subdomain

My `web.php` looks like

```
Route::group(
    [
        'domain'     => '{tenant}.' . config('app.url'),
    ],
    function () {
        $this->get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    }
);
```

My `HomeController` looks like

```
/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @param $tenant
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index($tenant)
{
    return view('home', compact('tenant'));
}
```

In `app.blade.php` file looks like

```
<a href="{{ route('home', ['tenant', $tenant]) }}">home</a>
```

Using Sub-domain routing we've to pass wildcard `{tenant}` value every time in when we use `route()` else it pops out this error

```
(3/3) ErrorException
Missing required parameters for [Route: home] [URI: home].
```

This is redundant all over the `controller` as well as `blade` file. Is there any solution to bind the `{wildcard}` by default **?**

Answer (score 1):

Make a new function that uses the existing `route()` function.

Example:

```
function mdroute ($routeName, $routeData = [])
{
    $tenant = request()->tenant;

    $routeData['tenant'] => $tenant;

    return route($routeName, $routeData);
}
```

Comment: where should I define this?

Comment: Add this function in a file you load with composer. Example in composer: `
`"autoload": { "files": [ "path/to/file" ] }`.

Comment: Do you mean use this method like helper function?

Comment: Correct. Quick search on how to do this: [Laravel Recipes](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/50/creating-a-helpers-file)

Comment: Thanks it was helpful.